How to package a Python program that uses GDAL into an executable file using PyInstaller？
I want to package my Python code that uses GDAL into an executable file using PyInstaller, but I keep encountering missing dependencies. Can someone provide a detailed tutorial, including how to properly include the Proj library in the package?
I hope someone can provide a tutorial with complete code examples.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
